# SOSL Single Quote Issue

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a problem with sosl.

This is working fine :

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = null;  
string startAddress = 'hello';  
searchList = Search.query('FIND \'' +startAddress + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account');
```

But it is giving me an error if I write something like this:

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = null;  
string startAddress = 'Tom\'s Towing and Recovery';  

searchList = Search.query('FIND \'' +startAddress + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account');
```

`Error : System.QueryException: line 1:507 mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '''`

Please suggest a solution for this issue.
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please escape the input like so:

```
string startAddress = string.escapeSingleQuotes( 'Tom\'s Towing and Recovery' );
```